# Trying to dynamically add labels to a form, 37 to a column until there are 183 total

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to add five columns of labels to my form, with 37 labels in the first three columns and 35 in the fourth.  I'm trying to be a good programmer and avoid retyping code over and over again, so I'd like to handle all four columns in one loop if possible.  Here's what I've got so far.

```
        Label[] countLabel = new Label[200];
        int PointY = 20;
        int PointX = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 37; j++ )
            {
                countLabel[j] = new Label();
                countLabel[j].Location = new Point(PointX, PointY);
                countLabel[j].Text = Convert.ToString(j + 1);
                panel1.Controls.Add(countLabel[j]);
                PointY += countLabel[j].Height;
            }
            PointX+=100;
        }
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
for 0 through 3,
    for 0 through 36
        create a label
        set its text to the count + 1
        add it to the screen
        make the next label be just below this one
```

Then, after the first group of 37 is output, make the next column be to the right 100px.

Whenever this runs, the first 37 form perfectly, and then the 38th is shifted to the right but below number 37.  How can I reset the Y position so that the next column starts at the same Y position as the first column and goes all the way down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't a simple

```
PointY = 20;
```

just after the line

```
`PointX+=100;`
```

do it? It would reset Y and the next one would start from top.

Comment: Oh my God.  Yes, it definitely did fix it.  I don't know how that didn't cross my mind.  I did some major changes in my code while I was writing this question, so the structure was very different and that wouldn't have worked.  Thanks! -.-